# Calculating Hours Left In Work

Tags: google-sheets

I work for the railroad and I am trying to make a calculator to show how much longer I'm allowed to work. The most I can work in a single shift is 12 Hours, however if I am put in a hotel that time does not count towards the 12 hours. For Example.

Start Time 06:00
Go to Hotel 12:00
Leave Hotel 16:00
Work Until 22:00

So my total time working was 12 hours even though I was in a hotel for 4. What I'm trying to do is the same thing as above but have it tell me the "work Until" time automatically by entering in the other 3 times. Any Help would be much appreciated! I've been stuck on this one for a while now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make something like this, using this formula (adapt the column letters to your spreadsheet)

> =TIMEVALUE("12:00")+A2+C2-B2

[image]

Comment: Or as an array for the entire column, in D2: =arrayformula(IF(A2:A="","", TIMEVALUE ("12:00")+A2:A+C2:C-B2:B))

Comment: That's amazing thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad it's useful!

Comment: If sometimes your working hours start in one day and end in the first hours of the next day, that could be solved with some conditionals too. Let me know